# Pushing an object to json array in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck with the json arrays into SQL Server. I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15, but I cannot figure out how to push to the existing array.

It works fine with an array of strings:

```
SET @info=JSON_MODIFY(@info, 'append $.skills', 'Azure')
```

but it seems it doesn't work with objects (or I am missing something here).

This is what I've tried so far :

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =  '{
   "changes":[
      {
         "logid":1,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"0",
         "newvalue":"637049"
      },
      {
         "logid":2,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"637049",
         "newvalue":"637041"
      }
     ]
}'

select ISJSON(@json) -- 1

select JSON_QUERY(@json, '$.changes')
--displays
--[
--   {
--      "logid":1,
--      "changedfield":"site",
--      "oldvalue":"0",
--      "newvalue":"637049"
--   },
--   {
--      "contactlogid":516870,
--      "changedfield":"site",
--      "oldvalue":"0",
--      "newvalue":"637049"
--   }
--]

-- now I want to push to the changes array

declare @json1 as nvarchar(max) = '{
   "changes":[
      {
         "logid":1,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"0",
         "newvalue":"637049"
      },
      {
         "logid":2,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"637049",
         "newvalue":"637041"
      }
     ]
}'

select JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $.changes', @json1)

-- the result 

--{
--   "changes":[
--      {
--         "logid":1,
--         "changedfield":"site",
--         "oldvalue":"0",
--         "newvalue":"637049"
--      },
--      {
--         "logid":2,
--         "changedfield":"site",
--         "oldvalue":"637049",
--         "newvalue":"637041"
--      },
--      "{\r\n   \"changes\":[\r\n      {\r\n         \"logid\":1,\r\n         \"changedfield\":\"site\",\r\n         \"oldvalue\":\"0\",\r\n         \"newvalue\":\"637049\"\r\n      },\r\n      {\r\n         \"logid\":2,\r\n         \"changedfield\":\"site\",\r\n         \"oldvalue\":\"637049\",\r\n         \"newvalue\":\"637041\"\r\n      }\r\n\t ]\r\n}"
--   ]
--}

select JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $.changes', (select json_query(@json1,'$.changes')))

-- result -- it creates two arrays

--{
--   "changes":[
--      {
--         "logid":1,
--         "changedfield":"site",
--         "oldvalue":"0",
--         "newvalue":"637049"
--      },
--      {
--         "logid":2,
--         "changedfield":"site",
--         "oldvalue":"637049",
--         "newvalue":"637041"
--      },
--      [
--         {
--            "logid":1,
--            "changedfield":"site",
--            "oldvalue":"0",
--            "newvalue":"637049"
--         },
--         {
--            "logid":2,
--            "changedfield":"site",
--            "oldvalue":"637049",
--            "newvalue":"637041"
--         }
--      ]
--   ]
--}
```

Do you have any idea how to push an object into the existing array?

Answer (score 3):

I could solve your problem, but I don't know I there a better way to do it:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =  '{
   "changes":[
      {
         "logid":1,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"0",
         "newvalue":"637049"
      },
      {
         "logid":2,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"637049",
         "newvalue":"637041"
      }
     ]
}'

declare @json1 as nvarchar(max) = '{
   "changes":[
      {
         "logid":3,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"0",
         "newvalue":"637049"
      },
      {
         "logid":4,
         "changedfield":"site",
         "oldvalue":"637049",
         "newvalue":"637041"
      }
     ]
}'

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append strict $.changes',JSON_QUERY(value,N'$')) FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.changes')

PRINT @json
```

And the result is :

```
{
       "changes":[
          {
             "logid":1,
             "changedfield":"site",
             "oldvalue":"0",
             "newvalue":"637049"
          },
          {
             "logid":2,
             "changedfield":"site",
             "oldvalue":"637049",
             "newvalue":"637041"
          }
         ,{
             "logid":3,
             "changedfield":"site",
             "oldvalue":"0",
             "newvalue":"637049"
          },{
             "logid":4,
             "changedfield":"site",
             "oldvalue":"637049",
             "newvalue":"637041"
          }]
    }
```

Comment: I added strict to answer, I think you have made mistake in position of strict, it is after append

Comment: I need one column with a default value to be getutcdate(), do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> With JSON_MODIFY you can update only one property. If you have to do
> multiple updates, you can use multiple JSON_MODIFY calls.

Hence, you can only update/append one value in an array with a single JSON_MODIFY() call.

@Json1 has two values in its changes:[] array and you have to use two nested json_modify() calls to append both values into @json:

```
select JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $.changes', json_query(@json1,'$.changes[0]')), 'append $.changes', json_query(@json1,'$.changes[1]'));
```

The answer posted by Amirhossein Yari, does the same (multiple JSON_MODIFY() calls) in a slightly different way.

Comment: this is great answer, but if you add strict before the append it shows an error. JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'a' is found at position 7. but still, this is valid json object :o it seems like strict (the validation) for the JSON is bugged?

I posted this comment twice, on the first answer and here, it seems like strict validation is bugged!!!!

Comment: ..@LoverBugs...tried `'append strict $.changes'` and the execution was normal (strict needs to go after the append, it is in the documentation : `path has the following syntax: [append] [ lax | strict ] $.<json path>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

Comment: I need one column with a default value to be getutcdate(), do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: ..@LoverBugs... do you want to add a new datetime column (which has getutcdate() default value) to a table?

Comment: yes, that's correct, but that column to be into the json object